# Can "bytes" take in value as a hex?

Tags: remix

While trying to upload a public key on Ethereum, I have faced a problem.

Given the following code in Solidity browser, it seems that I can only insert `string` values (using the browser compiler). For example, when I "create" and "set" values as "0x1234", it outputs:

> "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000063078313233340000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

What I want was something like "0x1234" but instead of that it interprets as a `string`. The work around is use bytesN where N is actual number of bytes. But then it becomes a static. Could anyone help?

```
contract SimpleStorage {
    bytes storedData;
    function set(bytes x) {
        storedData = x;
    }
    function get() constant returns (bytes retVal) {
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

Yes, instead of the above code, I can do as the following where I set bytes to `bytes2`. Then I can put "0x12", which would output "0x12". But Can I do it without being static?

```
contract SimpleStorage
{
    bytes2 storedData;
    function set(bytes2 x) {
        storedData = x;
    }
    function get() constant returns (bytes2 retVal) {
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can have an up to date look at literal syntax for Solidity and Vyper [here](http://reference.auditless.com/cheatsheet).

This includes the hex literal syntax for byte/string types as written below.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure the other responses answered this question and I came upon it recently.

Per [the Solidity docs](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html) you can now cast a fixed hex value to `bytes`, e.g.

```
bytes memory foo = hex"01";
```

will give you `foo == 0x01`.

BEWARE

This is not very well documented yet: the new syntax for hardcoding hex values in solidity has a major pitfall that is guaranteed to send some smart contracts crashing into the wall:

- the new syntax (bytes8 b = hex"1234") pads with zeroes to the right.
- the old syntax (uint64 u = 0x1234), pads zeroes to the left.

Below is a snippet that shows you the mess you can get if you use the new syntax as drop in for the old:

```
function showAddrFromUint() public pure returns (address r){
    uint160 t = 0x12345678ff0102;
    r = address(t);
}
// WILL RETURN: address: r 0x0000000000000000000000000012345678ff0102
// execution cost : 264 gas

function showAddrFromBytes() public pure returns (address r){
    bytes20 t = hex"12345678ff0102";
    r = address(t);
}
//WILL RETURN: address: r 0x12345678Ff010200000000000000000000000000
// execution cost : 226 gas
```

Answer (score 2):

try to use uint instead :

```
contract Ballot {
 uint public  key = 0x123A1; // A hex constant

}
```

you will get : "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000123a1"

Comment: Thanks! but the reason I wanted to use bytes was 1) dynamic 2)more intuitive to use bytes instead of int.

Comment: In that case, browser compiler has a limitation that I can express hex in bytesN while I cannot express hex in bytes?

Answer (score 1):

To create a binary out of your hex string, use [`web3.toAscii()`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3toascii); and to convert back to hex, use [`web3.toHex()`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3tohex). Like so:

```
// In Javascript
var txHash = simple.set(web3.toAscii("0x1234"), { from: account });
// And to retrieve
var returned = simple.get().toHex();
```

Comment: Thanks! but the reason I wanted to use bytes was 1) dynamic 2)more intuitive to use bytes instead of int.

Comment: In that case, browser compiler has a limitation that I can express hex in bytesN while I cannot express hex in bytes?

Comment: I do not understand why you mention `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Solidity code to convert `bytes` to hex `bytes`:

```
function toHex(bytes memory data) public pure returns(bytes memory res) {
    res = new bytes(data.length * 2);
    bytes memory alphabet = "0123456789abcdef";
    for (uint i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        res[i*2 + 0] = alphabet[uint256(uint8(data[i])) >> 4];
        res[i*2 + 1] = alphabet[uint256(uint8(data[i])) & 15];
    }
}
```